# Using the result of one query inside another query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I need to get a subset of one of my tables, and then use these id's in another query, is this possible?

Ideally, I need to use the result of this query:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, co12
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

inside this query:

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = CONCAT(col1, '_1')
WHERE id IN (ABOVE_QUERY)
```

Comment: What's the problem.. just insert your first query as is into the brackets of the second query - done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE
  table INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as m_id
                    FROM table
                    GROUP BY col1, co12
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t1
  ON table.id = t1.m_id
SET col1 = CONCAT(col1, '_1')
```

In MySQL you need to use a JOIN because you aren't allowed to update a table referenced in a subquery. And you probably need to use an aggregated function on the ID returned by your subquery.